# how to show content of page in to div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to show a content of url page( like https://www.google.fr ) in to `<div>` using JQuery but without success. Something like this :

```
<div id="contUrl">
.. content of google.fr page
</div>
```

help please :)

Comment: can you describe us more briefly?

Comment: iframe is one of the easy ways to do this, `<iframe src="https://www.google.fr"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You can load a site in a div using jQuery:

```
 <div id="siteloader"></div>

 <script>
     $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://google.fr" />');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try iframe tag**

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">

</iframe>
```